# Confusion in the C code on returning a value

Tags: c, return

I have written a function that has a return type of ListEntry created with typedef as follows

```
ListEntry RetrieveList(Position p,List *list)
{   if(p<0 || p>=list->count)
   {    Error("Invalid Position");
    return;
   }
else{
    SetPosition(p,list);
    ListEntry x=list->current->entry;
    return x;
  }
}
```

It checks whether the position is valid or not. If the position is not valid I don't want to return anything from the function . Please Help !

Comment: This function has to return a `ListEntry` value; perhaps you should return a pointer to `ListEntry`, and a null pointer if the position is not valid. Alternatively, you could return a specific `ListEntry` value that signals that the position was invalid. What exactly is a `ListEntry`?

Comment: It is a datatype I created using typedef.  typedef int ListEntry

Comment: Can you return `-1` to signal an invalid position condition?

Comment: I have done with using pointer as you said ! How can I show you the code for review ?

Comment: Click on `edit` under your post and add an update below the original question, or you could post your own self-answer if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RetrieveList()` function, as defined, must return a `ListEntry` value. One possibility, without changing the function signature, is to choose a return value that can signal an invalid position condition. Since `ListEntry` is a `typedef` for `int`, according to OP comments, an integer value that can not represent a `ListEntry` could be chosen; perhaps `-1`:

```
ListEntry RetrieveList(Position p, List *list)
{   if (p<0 || p >= list->count) {
        Error("Invalid Position");
        return -1;
    } else {
        SetPosition(p, list);
        ListEntry x = list->current->entry;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could change the function signature for `RetrieveList()` to return a pointer to `ListEntry`. Then a null pointer can be returned in the event of an invalid position condition. But, to make this work you need to have a `ListEntry` object for the returned pointer to point to. This can't be defined locally within `RetrieveList()`, since the lifetime of such local variables ends after the function has returned (making any pointers that point to them invalid). A `ListEntry` object could be allocated using `malloc()`, but then this object will need to be deallocated later:

```
ListEntry * RetrieveList(Position p, List *list)
{   if (p<0 || p >= list->count) {
        Error("Invalid Position");
        return NULL;
    } else {
        SetPosition(p, list);

        /* allocate a ListEntry object, but must remember to free() */
        ListEntry *x = malloc(sizeof *x);

        /* should also check that allocation was successful before using */
        *x = list->current->entry;

        return x;
    }
}
```

The above code should also check the value returned from `malloc()` to be sure that the allocation was successful. Instead of using `malloc()`, you could pass a pointer to a `ListEntry` object defined in the calling function. There is no need to remember to `free()` anything with this approach, but it may seem clumsy:

```
ListEntry * RetrieveList(Position p, List *list, ListEntry *lent)
{   if (p<0 || p >= list->count) {
        Error("Invalid Position");
        lent = NULL;
    } else {
        SetPosition(p, list);
        *lent = list->current->entry;
    }

    return lent;
}
```

This would be called like this:

```
ListEntry lentry;
if (RetrieveList(pos, list_ptr, &lentry) == NULL) {
    /* Handle invalid position */
} else {
    /* Proceed; lentry holds the value from list->current->entry */
}
```

I would probably go for the first option, since that is the most straightforward. Also, consider removing the `typedef`s, since these only serve to obfuscate the code; better to know what types are being used unless there is a good reason to hide this information.

Comment: at 2nd code example : `return -1;` --> `return NULL;` ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY-- oops! Thanks for catching that :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using pointer as follows

```
ListEntry *RetrieveList(Position p,List *list)
{   if(p<0 || p>=list->count)
{    Error("Invalid Position");
    return NULL;
}
else{
    SetPosition(p,list);
    ListEntry y=list->current->entry;
    ListEntry *x=&y;
    return x;
}
}
```

Comment: Do not use `y`. Because `&y` is the address of `y`, not the address of `list->current->entry`. : E.g `return &list->current->entry;` instead of.

Comment: What is `Error`; a macro or function  you have defined?

Comment: `y` is a local variable, whose lifetime ends once the function `RetrieveList()` has ended. You can't return a pointer to a local variable, since the object pointed to won't exist after the function returns.

Comment: Then what can I do ? Also error just prints the message !

Comment: Did you see my earlier comment about returning `-1` (or some other value that can't be a valid `ListEntry` value) if the position is invalid? This is probably what I would do.